Create an Azure Policy for an array of allowed tag names - not a parameter per tag name
I'm trying to create a policy that checks all tag names in an array and audits if no allowed values are found. I would like to accomplish this without creating a parameter for each tag name.
Here is the policy to detect 1 or more tag names:
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName1'),  ']')]",
          "exists": "false"
        },
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName2'),  ']')]",
          "exists": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "tagName1": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name 1",
        "description": "Name of first tag, such as 'environment'"
      }
    },
    "tagName2": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name 2",
        "description": "Name of second tag, such as 'owner'"
      }
    }
  }
}

I'm looking to do the checks in a single array. Just like the Allowed locations policy. So the parameter would be like this:
"parameters": {
            "tagNames": {
                "type": "Array",
                "metadata": {
                    "description": "List of tag names to audit",
                    "displayName": "Tag Names"
                },
                "allowedValues": [
                    "environment",
                    "costCenter",
                    "owner"
                ]
            }
        },

Is this possible?
If not, could someone explain why? For my understanding. Thanks


reate an Azure Policy for an array of allowed tag names - not a parameter per tag name.

Here is the updated policy to use array of values.
   {
     "mode": "All",
     "policyRule": {
       "if": {
         "not": {
           "anyOf": [
             {
               "field": "tags",
               "exists": "true"
             },
             {
               "allOf": [
                 {
                   "field": "tags",
                   "exists": "false"
                 },
                 {
                   "not": {
                     "field": "tags[*]",
                     "in": "[parameters('tagNames')]"
                   }
                 }
               ]
             }
           ]
         }
       },
       "then": {
         "effect": "audit"
       }
     },
     "parameters": {
       "tagNames": {
         "type": "Array",
         "metadata": {
           "displayName": "Tag Names",
           "description": "List of tag names to audit"
         },
         "allowedValues": [
           "environment",
           "costCenter",
           "owner"
         ]
       }
     }
   }


Policy Assignment:

